# WearOs Physical Home click event detect programmatically in JetPack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, android-hardware

**Is physical button click event is possible to get programmatically in jetpackCompose** and whatever if YES then i need an solution or some ideas about how can i achieve this and if NO , Then i need reason that why i can't do this,Here i am Creating small game will work in wearOS device eg samsung watch 4 which has 2 physical button , 1st button behave as home and 2nd button behave as back press and here i am getting click event for back press a 2nd button, **But fail/Not getting click event for 1st PHYSICAL button a Home button**, hope you got me what i am looking for, Thanks.

As per documentation available in development.android.com Link : https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/user-input/physical-buttons#metadata
Here i try to implement exact code and also try many ways to get a Home Button click event, But i wont get any good result of success.

Comment: That button is restricted to only be handled by the OS itself, no app can intercept it (just like how they cannot intercept the home button on Android phones).

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake for the valuable response .